# Getting NSInvalidArgumentsException when deleting uitableviewcells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I implemented the commitEditingStyle method to delete a row from my tableview. If I simply put `[timersArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` the row deletes just fine. The only problem is that it does not animate so I tried putting this:

```
[self->tableView beginUpdates];
[self->tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:timersArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self->tableView endUpdates];
```

but when I try and delete something it brings up this:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Timer row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ed37b0'
```

I thought it was because the `timersArray` is a NSMuttableArray and not a NSArray but that did not change anything. Can someone help me find out how to fix this? Anything will help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a little more of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]` in place of `timersArray` in order for that to work I had to place the `[timersArray removeRowAtIndex:indexPath.row]` above the `[self->tableView beginUpdates]` and at that point it worked!